# ReactJS: why does my react main app component renders many times when it is triggered by keyboard key instead of a mouseclick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

Basically I'm working on a drum machine app and I just noticed that when I try to press a pad with a keyboard key instead of mouse click, the component gets re-rendered over 10 times when it is supposed to be only once. Why would it be happening?

I have `componentDidMount()` set up to listen for the keydown and keyup events:

```
componentDidMount() {
   const setKeyDown = (event) => { this.setState({ keyPressed: event.key.toUpperCase() }) }
   const setKeyUp = (event) => { this.setState({ keyPressed: "" }) }

   document.addEventListener('keydown', setKeyDown)
   document.addEventListener('keyup', setKeyUp)
}
```

`componentWillUnmount`:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   const setKeyUp = (event) => { this.setState({ keyPressed: "" }) }
   document.addEventListener('keyup', setKeyUp)
}
```

and `componentDidUpdate` to check for any keyboard events and click to click a button whenever a corresponding key is pressed:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.keyList.includes(this.state.keyPressed) && this.state.power) {
    let buttonClicked = document.getElementById(this.state.keyPressed + "-button")
    buttonClicked.click()
  }
}
```

The `button` is stored in a separate stateless component:

```
function Drumpad(props) {
   return (
      <button 
        type="button"
        className="drum-pad"
        id={props.keyValue+"-button"}
        name={props.keyValue} 
        value={props.audioBank.value}
        onClick={props.handleClick}
        disabled={!props.power}>
        {props.keyValue}
        <Audio keyValue={props.keyValue} audioSource={props.audioBank.audioSource} />
     </button>
  )
}
```

And it triggers `handleClick` in the main component:

```
handleClick(event) {
  const { id, name, value } = event.target
  this.setState({
    displayValue: value
  })
  var audio = document.getElementById(name)
  audio.volume = this.state.volume / 100.0
  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.currentTime = 0

  console.log(id)
}
```

I passed this `console.log(id)` here just for testing purposes and I noticed that whenever I click on corresponding button with my mouse it only prints this ID once in the console, but prints over 10 times same thing whenever I trigger the button with my keyboard key. What should be changed here in order to make my app render only once when it is triggered by the keyboard key?

```js
const BANK_ONE = {
  "Q": {
    padID: "pad-q",
    value: "Chord 1",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_1.mp3"
  },
  "W": {
    padID: "pad-w",
    value: "Chord 2",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_2.mp3"
  },
  "E": {
    padID: "pad-e",
    value: "Chord 3",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Chord_3.mp3"
  },
  "A": {
    padID: "pad-a",
    value: "Shaker",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Give_us_a_light.mp3"
  },
  "S": {
    padID: "pad-s",
    value: "Open HH",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dry_Ohh.mp3"
  },
  "D": {
    padID: "pad-d",
    value: "Closed HH",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Bld_H1.mp3"
  },
  "Z": {
    padID: "pad-z",
    value: "Punchy Kick",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/punchy_kick_1.mp3"
  },
  "X": {
    padID: "pad-x",
    value: "Side Stick",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/side_stick_1.mp3"
  },
  "C": {
    padID: "pad-c",
    value: "Snare",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Brk_Snr.mp3"
  }
}

const BANK_TWO = {
  "Q": {
    padID: "pad-q",
    value: "Heater 1",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
  },
  "W": {
    padID: "pad-w",
    value: "Heater 2",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3"
  },
  "E": {
    padID: "pad-e",
    value: "Heater 3",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3"
  },
  "A": {
    padID: "pad-a",
    value: "Heater 4",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3"
  },
  "S": {
    padID: "pad-s",
    value: "Clap",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3"
  },
  "D": {
    padID: "pad-d",
    value: "Open HH",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3"
  },
  "Z": {
    padID: "pad-z",
    value: "Kick'n Hat",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3"
  },
  "X": {
    padID: "pad-x",
    value: "Kick",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3"
  },
  "C": {
    padID: "pad-c",
    value: "Closed HH",
    audioSource: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      power: true,
      volume: 100,
      bankSelection: true,
      displayValue: "",
      keyPressed: "",
      keyList: Object.keys(BANK_ONE),
      audioBank: BANK_ONE
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleVolumeChange = this.handleVolumeChange.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const setKeyDown = (event) => { this.setState({ keyPressed: event.key.toUpperCase() }) }
    const setKeyUp = (event) => { this.setState({ keyPressed: "" }) }
    
    document.addEventListener('keydown', setKeyDown)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', setKeyUp)
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    const setKeyUp = (event) => { this.setState({ keyPressed: "" }) }
    document.addEventListener('keyup', setKeyUp)
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.keyList.includes(this.state.keyPressed) && this.state.power) {
      let buttonClicked = document.getElementById(this.state.keyPressed + "-button")
      buttonClicked.click()
    }
  }
  
  handleClick(event) {
    const { id, name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      displayValue: value
    })
    var audio = document.getElementById(name)
    audio.volume = this.state.volume / 100.0
    audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.currentTime = 0
    
    console.log(id)
  }
  
  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, checked } = event.target
    const value = checked
    
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
    
    if (!this.state.power) {
      this.state({
        displayValue: "",
        keyList: [],
        audioBank: {}
      })
    } else {
      if (this.state.bankSelection) {
        this.setState({
          keyList: Object.keys(BANK_TWO),
          audioBank: BANK_TWO
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          keyList: Object.keys(BANK_ONE),
          audioBank: BANK_ONE
        })
      }
    }
  }
  
  handleVolumeChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="drum-machine">
        <Display displayValue={this.state.displayValue} />
        
        {this.state.keyList.map((d,i) => (
          <Drumpad
            power={this.state.power}
            keyValue={d} 
            audioBank={this.state.audioBank[d]}
            handleClick={this.handleClick} />
        ))}
        
        <Switch
          title={"Power"}
          name={"power"} 
          selection={this.state.power} 
          handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        
        <Switch
          title={"Bank"}
          name={"bankSelection"} 
          selection={this.state.bankSelection} 
          handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        
        <VolumeSlider volume={this.state.volume} handleVolumeChange={this.handleVolumeChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function Display(props) {
  return (
    <div id="display">
      {props.displayValue}
    </div>
  )
}

function Drumpad(props) {
  return (
    <button 
      type="button"
      className="drum-pad"
      id={props.keyValue+"-button"}
      name={props.keyValue} 
      value={props.audioBank.value}
      onClick={props.handleClick}
      disabled={!props.power}>
      {props.keyValue}
      <Audio keyValue={props.keyValue} audioSource={props.audioBank.audioSource} />
    </button>
  )
}

function Audio(props) {
  return (
    <audio 
      className="clip" 
      id={props.keyValue}
      src={props.audioSource} />
  )
}

function Switch(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p id={props.name}>{props.title}</p>
      <input 
          name={props.name}
          type="checkbox" 
          checked={props.selection}
          onChange={props.handleChange} />
    </div>
  ) 
}

function VolumeSlider(props) {
  return (
    <input 
      type="range"
      id="volumeSlider"
      name="volume"
      min="0" 
      max="100" 
      value={props.volume} 
      onChange={props.handleVolumeChange} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of code to look over, but at quick glance, it seems you are adding the event handler again when the component is removed from the DOM:

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
    const setKeyUp = (event) => { this.setState({ keyPressed: "" }) }
    document.addEventListener('keyup', setKeyUp)
  }
```

Surely you should be removing the handler: `removeEventListener`